# Display an ApexBubbleSeries of data points with their standard deviation as an ApexRangeSeries behind (Blazor wrapper for ApexCharts)

Tags: c#, blazor, apexcharts

I need to display a series of data points with their standard deviations shaded behind them using ApexCharts in a Blazor wrapper:
[sample charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZjfy.png)
[Blazor-ApexCharts wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbdhf.png)

I tried combining an `ApexBubbleSeries` with an `ApexRangeSeries` but I get an Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. whenever the 2 series are within the same `<ApexChart></>` tag:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upWUY.png)

```
<ApexChart Height="100" TItem="GraphDataPoint" Title="" Options="_options" @ref="_chart">
        <ChildContent>
            <ApexBubbleSeries TItem="GraphDataPoint"
                              Items="GraphData"
                              XValue="i => i.xAxis"
                              YAggregate="i => i.First().yAxis"
                              ZAggregate="_ => 1"/>
            <ApexRangeSeries TItem="GraphStandardDeviationRange"
                             Items="StandardDeviations"
                             YMinValue="range => range.Min"
                             YMaxValue="range => range.Max"
                             XValue="range => range.XValue" />
        </ChildContent>
    </ApexChart>
```

Is there a solution to combining these 2 data series types? Are we on the right path or is there a better way to go about this?

Thank you in advance!